# H3 doesn't display with CSS inline, but with external CSS-File

Tags: html, css

I copied/wrote a simple "image grid" in a simple html file. First I used an external css file. It worked fine. But since I can't load an external css file at work into the page (only access to html code between `<body>`) I tried to copy all the attributes to the style inline. But then, the h3 disappears. Can somebody help me?

The working external CSS File:

```
<script>

.image-zoom-container {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 0px;
}
.zoom-container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33.33%;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    vertical-align: top;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.zoom-container img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.zoom-container .zoom-caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
.zoom-container .zoom-caption h3 {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 23% 0 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
</script>
```

With this HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<div class="image-zoom-container">
<div class="zoom-container">
<span style="zoom-caption">
<h3>Text</h3>
</span>
<img src="test.png" />
</div>
</div>
```

But with inline, it doesn't work:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="list-style: none; font-size: 0px;">
    <div style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; display: inline-block; width: 33.33%; border: 1px solid #fff; vertical-align: top; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box;">
        <a href="#">
            <span style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; z-index: 10;">
                <h3 style="display: block; text-align: center; font-size: 1.5em;">Costa Rica</h3>
            </span>
            <img style="display: block; width: 100%; height: auto;" src="Selection_009.png" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid...`span` elements should not contain block level elements like an `h3`. Validate first! and why are you using inline styles?

Comment: Change `<span style="zoom-caption">` to `<span class="zoom-caption">`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but this didnt help. The site works as html with an external css file (the first two code's). But like i said, i am not able to change the whole html file at work, only between body tags. So i try to archive the same result with inline css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inline styles in the bottom block are not the same as the styles in the CSS file.
For instance, the div that used to be `.zoom-container` does not have a font size specified. Therefore it inherits the font size from its parent (being `0px`), making the text within it invisibly small. Yes, the `h3` does have `font-size: 1.5em`, but 1.5 × 0px is still 0.

Solution: copy *all* the CSS from the .css file.

Also, you shouldn't put a `h3` in a `span`. Validate your HTML before publishing!

Comment: Thanks! This was really the problem... My bad. I am pretty new to css and html and dint know that.